Bounding $\sum_{k=-N}^{N} |a_k|$ where $a_k=\hat{P_N}(k)$ and $P_N(x)$ is a trigonometric polynomial of degree N
$$ \sum_{k=-N}^N |a_k| \le \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi} |P_n(x)| \mathrm dx+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3} \int_0^{2\pi} |P'_N(x)|^2 \mathrm dx $$
I need to prove that inequality above:
My approach was to write $|a_k| = |a_k| \cdot k \cdot \frac{1}{k}$ for all $k \neq 0$. Then, using the QM-GM inequality, we obtain:
$$|a_k| \leq \frac{1}{2}\left( |a_k|^2 k^2 + \frac{1}{k^2} \right).$$
Now, we know that the absolute values of the Fourier coefficients of $P'_N(x)$ are $|a_k|^2 k^2$, so we have:
$$ \sum_{k=-N}^{N} |a_k|^2 k^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |P'_N(x)|^2 \, dx.$$
We can write this since we have Parseval's identity for the finite sum. also note that the $0$'s fourier coefficient of the derivative is $0$ by  $\hat{f'(n)}=in\hat f(n)$
and $P_N(x)$ is certainly continuous. So I did manage to work out the second integral (the derivative one) but how can I attack the first one? and get rid of the sum of  $\frac{1}{k^2}$
since $a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} P_N(x) \, dx$
we must have $|a_0| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |P_N(x)| \, dx$
thus
$|a_0| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi} |P_N(x)| \, dx$
now for the derivative integral:
We know from Cauchy-Schwarz and Parseval's theorem that:
$\sum_{k \neq 0} |a_k| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{k^2}} \sqrt{\sum_{k \neq 0} k^2 |a_k|^2}.$
and
$\sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{1}{k^2} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = 2 \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}.$
plugging in everything we obtain:
$\sum_{k \neq 0} |a_k| \leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |P'_N(x)|^2 dx}.$
which can be simplified to
$\sum_{k \neq 0} |a_k| \leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{2\pi} |P'_N(x)|^2 dx}.$
thus in the end we get the following:
$\sum_{k=-N}^{N} |a_k| = |a_0| + \sum_{k \neq 0} |a_k| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |P_N(x)| dx + \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{2\pi} |P'_N(x)|^2 dx}.$
So close yet still not there yet!
any ideas would be very much appreciated!

What is $P_N$ in relation to the coefficients $a_k$?

I think that the problem with your approach is that you derive a bound that is independent of the coefficients (i.e. the $1/k^2$ term.) It is impossible to bound this bound by integrals involving $P_N$, as one can trivially multiply $P_N$ by $\epsilon$ and take $\epsilon\to 0$, defeating the bound. I think you need to try again with another inequality that will keep a part of $a_k$ in both terms.

The problem is that I just don't know what kind of inequalities can help me since I am essentially trying to bound the sum of the absolute value of the fourier coefficients and  there are not a lot of inequalities that I can play around with

where does this come from?

A test in Real analysis II. I will now edit the question since I manage to get something but still not the result itself.

There is something wrong with the inequality as written as it is not true; consider $$P_A(x)=\frac{5+8\cos x+4 \cos 2x+\cos 3x}{A}$$ Note that LHS is $18/A$ as when we write it in exponential form each coefficient except the first gets halved but appears twice.
Now it is well-known that $AP_A(x)=(1+\cos x)(1+2\cos x)^2 \ge 0$, so $$ \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi} |P_A(x)| \mathrm dx=5\sqrt {2\pi}/A <18/A$$
However $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3} \int_0^{2\pi} |P'_A(x)|^2 \mathrm dx=C/A^2$$ so if we pick a large enough $A$ the inequality clearly fails

I thought it looked strange that the right-hand side doesn't scale like the left-hand side (the left-hand side being an upper bound for the supremum of the trig polynomial).
